# Regex - match data between nth space and stop at nth space

Tags: regex, parsing, logging, syslog, event-id

I am trying to capture/parse event log data, windows and linux using regex in a log collection tool.  I can't seem to find a regex that tells me how to capture only data between the nth space and stop matching after the following nth space.

For example:

```
<11>Mar 7 09:55:54 blahblah blahblahblah textiwant blahblahblahblah
```

How do I capture only textiwant? I realize I can get to textiwant by (\S+ \S+ \S+ \S+ \S+) but I am baffled as to how to keep only textiwant, nothing before and nothing after.

Thank you!

Comment: Capture only that `\S` that matches your word.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of capturing groups and anchors:

```
^(?:\S+\s+){5}(\S+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ZGIod4/2/).

Comment: Could be shortened to `^(?:\S+ ){5}(\S+)`

Comment: for some reason this one does not work in my system but the one below works.  I understand that this should work but I am assuming there are some constrains on my system that is interpreting the regex?

Comment: Maybe it's the anchor at the beginning. Try removing the `^`

Comment: Could it be because theres actually 2 spaces between Mar and 7.. Mar  7

Comment: Jan's original suggestion should account for that, but my shortened suggestion does not.

Comment: So my system is doing the 'Full Match'.  How do I pull only the group 1 match?

Comment: Which programming language / tool do you use?